# Transluscent StatusBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Please how can I achieve this `transluscent` effect on the status bar in flutter? I wish to use this on android devices `<= ANDROID_19` and also on Lollipop.

[image]

Here is my current Code implementation

```
ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light();
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark();

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent),
  );
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainWidget(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you imported `package:flutter/services.dart`?

Comment: Yes. Imported. Still didn't work.

Comment: Can you add to your question the error that are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can change color of `StatusBar`, like below

```
final ThemeData kIOSTheme = new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
  primaryColor: Colors.grey[100],
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
);

final ThemeData kDefaultTheme = new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
  primaryColor: Colors.black,
  accentColor: Colors.black,
  brightness: Brightness.light,
);

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
     SystemUiOverlayStyle(
     statusBarColor: Colors.white, //top bar color
     statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //top bar icons
     systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white, //bottom bar color
     systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //bottom bar icons
     )
  );
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
      .then((_) => runApp(new MyApp()));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Home',
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     theme: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
          ? kIOSTheme
          : kDefaultTheme,
     home: MyHomePage(title: 'Welcome Home'),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am testing this on KitKat and unfortunately, it didn't work.The statusbarcolor is still dark .

Answer (score 0):

Set the color to `Colors.transparent`

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// Some code...

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am testing this on KitKat and unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: @mekings If you showed your code maybe it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @mekings you have to add that code to your question, not in comments. Please edit your question.